# Change file association for unknown type

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to open a file that the Files app doesn't recognize. On clicking, it opens a window that just says "Filename, 32KB". Then I have to go to share, scroll right, click more, and then click to open with the app I want.

Is it possible to set this app as default?

Comment: Does the file have a filename extension?

Comment: @Allan Yes. [padding]